# Can I group taskbar icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Is there a way to group taskbar icons on windows 10? Probably via 3rd party software?

For example a group for office-programs, one for IDEs, one for several browsers and so on.

I think of a concept similar to ios and android, where you can group icons too by creating folders.

Comment: Just create a folder, put the shortcuts in it, then pin the folder to the taskbar. You can do similar things with the start menu tiles.

Comment: I can't pin multiple specific folders to the taskbar. I can pin the windows explorer only once

Comment: You can use this [workaround](http://www.intowindows.com/quickly-pin-folders-to-taskbar-in-windows-10/) to pin multiple shortcuts to folders on the taskbar

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to create shortcuts to everything you need. Place them in a folder, and then create a new toolbar on the task bar. Works fairly well for me.

P.S. Right click the task bar and see the toolbars options. The rest is fairly simple.

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a seperate dock. This is a free solution that I am using on Windows Server 2012 and it works totally fine:

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/rocketdock-stacks-docklet-not-just-a-dock-but-a-complete-desktop-organization-solution-windows/

Although this is totally separate from the taskbar so **it might not work for you**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Bins](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/default.aspx). It is able to group icons on the taskbar.

> To use Bins, drag one icon on top of another and drop into the bubble that appears. To ungroup, drag the icon back to the taskbar.

However:

> **Windows 10 limitations**
>
> On Windows 10, "Modern" apps are not yet supported, and cannot be placed into bins. Also, Bins will only work on your primary taskbar. If your system has multiple monitors, Bins will only appear on the primary screen.

**Note:** It only gives 14 days trial. After the trial period, you have to pay.

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the software.

Comment: They do not seem to support windows 11 FYI, and don't seem to intend to.