# Group different running program icons on taskbar in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

Imagine we have **Skype** and **Symphony** and **Cisco Jabber** running on Windows 10 PC.

Then in the taskbar we will have *three separate icons*

- one for Skype
- one for Symphony
- one for Jabber

**Q:** Is it possible to group those three icons into one?

*So we will not have three but just one icon where Skype, Symphony and Jabber will be grouped together*.

---

I saw [Can I group taskbar icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1279397/can-i-group-taskbar-icons) answer already and I created a folder named Communication and put shortcuts to Skype, Symphony and Jabber into this folder and I created New Toolbar based on this folder Communication. The only thing this does is : I have a toolbar on taskbar named Communication with the icons to Skype, Symphony, Jabber, but nothing else. When I start e.g. Symphony, it will have its separate icon on the taskbar. I want achieve to have *just one icon for all three running programs* on taskbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I group taskbar icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1279397/can-i-group-taskbar-icons)