# Windows 11 group taskbar icons

Tags: taskbar, icons, windows-11

Is it possible to group icons on the taskbar in windows 11. Probably using a 3rd party software or something.

I saw many of the other posts like this one but so far all the suggestions only work for windows 10.

[Can I group taskbar icons](https://superuser.com/questions/1279397/can-i-group-taskbar-icons)

I also tried taskbar groups, the open-source system but it is deprecated apparently.

I understand that windows 11 doesn't natively do this. I currently use start11 to reset the taskbar back to windows 10 and I am looking for another app/way that just allows grouping apps on the taskbar.

edit: added clarification.

Comment: Windows 11 natively cannot do what you want. Try Classic Shell or like software.

Comment: I understand that. I am looking for something similar to taskbargroups the opensource system found here https://github.com/tjackenpacken/taskbar-groups.